# Importing PKE in Python - KeyError= Hinglish when importing PKE

Tags: python, import, keyerror

I am trying to use `pke` for the first time. Every time I try to execute a code with it, it gives me the error below.

I installed `pke` using pip.

Any ideas on what I could do to fix this?

```
  import pke
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pke/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pke.base import LoadFile
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pke/base.py", line 31, in <module>
    lang_stopwords = {get_alpha_2(l): l for l in stopwords._fileids}
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pke/base.py", line 31, in <dictcomp>
    lang_stopwords = {get_alpha_2(l): l for l in stopwords._fileids}
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pke/base.py", line 29, in <lambda>
    get_alpha_2 = lambda l: LANGUAGE_CODE_BY_NAME[l]
KeyError: 'hinglish'
```

Comment: https://github.com/boudinfl/pke/issues/200

Answer (score 0):

By installing the latest version of pke from github it resolved the error

To pip install pke from github:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/boudinfl/pke.git
```